# USB device with a serial number and 3 LEDs

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, usb-device, eeprom, component-selection

I'm looking for a way to build a USB key. I have a bit of experience with the Arduino, however for this project that seems to be a bit of overkill.

The key should contain a unique serial number (EEPROM?), either to be programmed or factory-set (whatever is easier). Besides the serial number, I need to control 3 LEDs. Each LED has 3 states (on, off & blinking).

I was think to start with a [CP2102 based USB TTL UART](http://www.miniinthebox.com/cp2102-usb-2-0-to-ttl-uart-6pin-module-serial-converter_p391022.html).

For the EEPROM: [AT25010B](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT25010B.aspx) (SPI) or [AT24C01B](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT24C01B.aspx) (I<sup>2</sup>C) or [a dedicated chip](http://www.atmel.com/products/memories/serial/mac-eui-serial-number.aspx)

The software (linux) should talk to the RS232 port and be able to retrieve the serial number, and set each LED to the 3 different states.

I read about I<sup>2</sup>C and SPI. I seems SPI is easier to control, but you need more pins to hook it up.

**My questions are:**

1) What would be the better protocol I2C or SPI (in terms of 'easy' implementation)?

2) Assuming you can't hookup the LED's and the EEPROM direct to the UART. I  need some type PIC to facilitate the communication. What would be a could PIC for this?

*Not sure if it matters but: once I have a working prototype, I need to be able to batch produce a few hundreds of these.*

Comment: If you are familiar with Arduino, why not use a tiny one [E.g.1](http://tiny-circuits.com/products/tinyduino/) [E.g.2](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano) or make one up using a small Arduino-compatible AVR micro?

Comment: Small microcontroller (ATtiny), hand full discretes and some software: http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjdisplay.html USB has room for a serial number by design.

Comment: Heck, you could do this with a keyboard IC. Three leds (caps, num, scroll), controllable.

Comment: I know, but thought that with a arduino (even the tiny) it feels as overkill. The functional specs are 'super' simple. My lack of knowledge aside, was looking for the simplest (component wise) solution.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need an external EEPROM for this. Get a microcontroller with EEPROM instead, that's smaller and easier to use, because you don't need an SPI or I<sup>2</sup>C module anymore. Also, you can easily program the EEPROM from the computer.

So, basically, you want a PIC or other microcontroller with:

- (E)U(S)ART connection
- EEPROM
- 3 GPIO pins for the LEDs

Most microcontroller manufacturers have a part selection tool. For microchip, that's [MAPS](http://www.microchip.com/maps/main.aspx). That's how you can lookup which chip you need.

For these (very minimalistic) requirements, a very small chip enough. Have a look at the [PIC12F1822](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en544839): 8 pins, XLP if you need that, 256 bytes EEPROM, etc. This chip has *just* enough I/O pins for your three LEDs.

However, from your question it looks like you're a beginner in PIC, and then perhaps a somewhat bigger but easier to interface chip is a better start. Then have a look at the [PIC16F88](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010243): it has everything you need and more I/O pins, for more LEDs, if needed. The fun of the 16F88 is that it's easier to program it. For the 12F1822, they put everything in a small box and you have to initialize everything (a lot!) correctly, which can be hard, especially for a beginner. The 16F88 is easier to start with.

Comment: Super, thanks (absolute beginner!;-). For the moment there are 3 LEDs. I updated the question.  I look into those PIC's.

Comment: @Rogier you're welcome. I saw your update, the 12F1822 has _just_ enough I/O pins for three LEDs and a serial connection, but I'd strongly recommend you the 16F88!

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to get away with just a FTDI USB->serial IC like the [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm)

I have not used one for an application like this but [the datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) says it can have a serial number burned in during manufacture(e.g. for use as a security dongle) and the IO port can be configured to drive LEDs.

The FTDI chip has the advantage that the drivers are common and supported on many platforms.

Comment: Most USB-serial converters based on the FTDI chip have  4 I/O pins. Each pin can be independently and on-the-fly
programmed as an input or an output.
http://hackaday.com/2009/09/22/introduction-to-ftdi-bitbang-mode/
http://www.huitsing.nl/irftdi/
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-01_BitBang.pdf